# DBeaver not showing dbms_output

Tags: dbeaver

I'm using dbeaver version 5.1.3. When I use the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE method for oracle pl/sql it's output not shown anywhere. It has a output tab. It's also blank.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually you can use `DBMA_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in DBeaver (mine is version 4.3.2), maybe you were just looking at "wrong" output tab. I have attached a screenshot of my SQL editor to make my point clearer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! by the way, the buttons have move a bit, they are now in the bottom left of the sql query windows as very small squares :).

Comment: I still do not see any logs in the output tab, is there something I need to enable ?

Comment: is DBMS_OUTPUT not DBMA_OUTPUT

Answer (score 50):

You can enable server output console. (Ctrl+Shift+O)
If you expand the query pane, you are able to see two more buttons. (Server output console e Execution Log)

I can't really tell you the diference between this server output console and the output view tab you show on the print screen above.

Comment: Is this a comment?

Comment: Was really unable to find the output in any other way than this one, in DBeaver 6.2.2 version.

Answer (score 8):

shorcut Ctrl+Shift+O

Or You can view the output panel by clicking the 'View Server Output' button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The second (middle icon) is where you can see the output for your query as per December 2020 Dbeaver latest version.